# Route planner with distances for trains?

Tags: trains, planning, maps

Is there a route planner that includes the distance traveled by trains. Google maps and Apple Maps both state the time, but no information on how far the route is. I'd like to know this to compare C02 costs.

Comment: To compare CO2 costs you probably also need to know whether the route is electrified or not.

Answer (score 2):

[Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com) displays the mileage when the user clicks on the "Train" link after searching for a route.

For example, I just entered "San Jose CA" and "Redding CA" and was shown the distance as 290.4 miles:

[image]